# Why do my code lines after await not get called?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I have a problem with the following code. The firebase.login returns a Promise and I learned that, when I put "await" before, Javascript waits until the Promise delivers and then continues with the next line.I

But the next line(s) seem never to be triggered. What am I doing wrong? It also does not stop at the "debugger" mark.

````
    try {
      const user = await firebase.login(email, password);
      console.log("l1: ", user);
      debugger;
      props.history.replace("/impressum");
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error.message);
    }
  }```
````

Comment: Are you in an async function? Any errors in the console? Please post a reproduceable problem.

Comment: [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Maybe `const user = await firebase.login(email, password);` this line returns an error and control shifts to `catch(error)` block.

Comment: I think it more likely OP didn't put it in an async function and is getting a syntax error, but no way to tell for sure without more info

Comment: `firebase.login` What is this?, could you point to the source or docs.?

Answer (score 0):

The returned `Promise` from the `firebase.login();` call should be wrapped within an `async` function (which we cannot see from your snippet). As mentioned in the comments it's possible that the `catch` is being triggered, in which case you should be gracefully handling the error.

```js
// mock the firebase login Promise
const firebase = {
  async login(email, password) {
    return {
      email
    };
  }
};

(async() => {
  try {
    const [email, password] = [
      'joe.bloggs@example.com',
      'password123',
    ];
    const user = await firebase.login(email, password);

    console.log(user);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I got the solution from my new hero:

"Submit buttons submit forms.

When a form is submitted, the browser navigates to a new web page.

Since the page the JS program was running in has been navigated away from, that JS program exits. It does this before reaching console.log("l2");"

So, everthing I had to do was insert "event.preventDefault". In the tutorial the used a simple Button, that does not cause the form to submit. I used a bootstrap submit-button und thats why I think the form was always submitted.